# LNK2019 error with functions used in main with Visual Studio 2012 C++

Tags: c++, header

I receive the following error:

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   setup(void)" (?setup@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main 1>main.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl display(void)"
>   (?display@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main
>   1>C:\code\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2
>   unresolved externals

How do i resolve this?

Here is the main class, where the functions are used:

```
#include "interface.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    setup();
    display();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is interface.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "interface.h"
using namespace std;
class ui{
    void setup(){
        options[0][0]="Hello";
        options[1][0]="Hello";
        options[2][0]="Hello";
        options[3][0]="Hello";
        options[4][0]="Hello";
        options[5][0]="Hello";
        options[6][0]="Hello";
        options[7][0]="Hello";
        options[8][0]="Hello";
        options[9][0]="Hello";
    }
    void changeOption(int whatOption, string whatText,
                  string prop1, string prop2, string prop3, string prop4, string prop5){
        options[whatOption][0]=whatText;
        options[whatOption][1]=prop1;
        options[whatOption][2]=prop2;
        options[whatOption][3]=prop3;
        options[whatOption][4]=prop4;
        options[whatOption][5]=prop5;
    }
    void display(){
        for(int x=0;x<9;x++){
            cout<<options[x][0]<<endl;
        }
    }
};
```

and here is interface.h

```
#include <string>
//#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifndef INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
#define INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
    void setup();
    extern string options[10][6];
    void changeOption(int whatOption, string whatText, string prop1, string prop2, string prop3, string prop4, string prop5);
    void display();
#endif INTERFACE_H
```

Comment: it won't help you much in this current situation, but maybe in long term programming: in `inteface.h`, don't put anything outside of the include guards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare these as global functions.

However, your implementation defines them inside of `class ui{`.

You can remove the `class ui{` and matching closing parenthesis and it should work correctly.

Comment: Now it says this: interface.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > (* options)[6]" (?options@@3PAY05V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A)

Comment: define string options[10][6]; in `interface.cpp` somewhere like this: `string options[10][6];`. you declared it with `extern` in `interface.h`, promising you will define it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setup()` function is inside the `ui` namespace but when you try to use it, you're not specifying that. Try `ui::setup();` instead.

Same solution for `display()`.

In addition to this, you need to reexamine your interface.h header file. Here, you're declaring these functions without enclosing the declaration in their namespace. This is why you were able to compile the main() function but not able to link it.

Comment: This won't actually be enough to do it, as they're implemented in the "ui" class, but not that way in the header...